# Css code not working only when using classes

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to center the text in a `div`. I found this code on this site that works:

```
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;      
}

<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</div>
```

But when I try to add classes instead of global div or span, the code does not work anymore:

```
.titleDiv {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.titleSpan {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;      
}

<div class="titleDiv">
      <span class="titleSpan">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      </span>
</div>
```

Any ideas why it does not work? I'm using VS2010 Pro.

Edit:

The css code is in a separate css file that is imported ok (when I change the background color in code then I can see the change in Chrome)

Edit 2:

Here is the entire markup:

Default.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body class="titleDiv">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="titleDiv">
      <span class="titleSpan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

StyleSheet.css file:

```
.titleDiv {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.titleSpan {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;      
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "it does not work" means?

Comment: It appears to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5jrVh/

Comment: Yes, in jsfiddle it works, with visual studio does not work

Comment: @kovacslorand - Visual Studio is just the IDE.  What do you mean it doesn't work with VS?  You are wanting to see it work in the designer vs in your browser?

Comment: @Code Maverick I mean when I run it with visual studio --> view the site in Chrome

Comment: @kovacslorand - You should probably show your entire markup.  How are you including the CSS? Via a file in the head section or a style tag?

Comment: I tried your exact code and it works fine here. the only thing i see is that mine is setting `MYPROJECTNAME._Default` instead of just `_Default`  Also make sure your browser is up to date.

Comment: @Jim: Can you post a screenshot with the site? Also, what version of visual studio you use? Thank you.

Comment: @kovacslorand it just shows your div's centered :) I'm using `Visual Studio Ultimate 2013`

Comment: @Jim There should be a gap of 100 pixels vertically between the top and the text. Is the gap there?

Comment: @kovacslorand No Sir there is no gap, and there shouldn't be. As u assigning the same height on the `body` as on the `div`. I personally dont see any reason to apply a `div` style to a `body ether.` I updated my answer in what will produce a gap from 100px with titleDiv.

Answer (score 0):

if the css is in the same file use `<style> </style>` tags:

```
<style type="text/css">    
    .titleDiv {
        width: 250px;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .titleSpan {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: normal;
    }
</style>
```

What will produce a gap from 100px:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="titleDiv"></div> <%--The gap--%>
    <div class="titleDiv">
        <span class="titleSpan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have separate css file that is imported ok (when I change then background color in code the I can see the change in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your CSS in a  tag, e.g.

```
<style>
.titleDiv {
   width: 250px;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 100px;
   ext-align: center;
}

.titleSpan {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   ine-height: normal;      
}
</style>
<div>
content
</div
```

Comment: I have separate css file that is imported ok (when I change the background color in code the I can see the change in Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be a solution for you.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey96S/)
is the link

HTML

```
<body>    
    <div class="titleDiv">
         <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    </div>   
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 .titleDiv {      
   background-color:red;
   text-align:center;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
   width:500px;
   height:200px;   
}

.titleDiv span{
   background-color:aqua;
   position:relative;
   top:45%
}
```

top:45% must be
top:TOTAL HEIGHT(which is 200px here) - SPAN HEIGHT(WHICH IS JUST A FONT SIZE AND ITS PADDING):